# How does personality reputation work?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I've been playing, and I have noticed that I have picked up several personality reputations, mostly by my diaglogue choices.

Looking at them, I get the feeling it just adds up the number of times you pick that type of response.

The official strategy guide says that each reputation has three "ranks or titles" which reflect your consistent behavior. The personality types are listed as:

- Benevolent: charitable, kind, soft, or weak.
- Cruel: merciless, sadistic, brutal, or imperious.
- Clever: sarcastic, sassy, foppish, or irreverent.
- Stoic: tight-lipped, cool-headed, or simple-minded.
- Aggressive: hot-headed, bold, or impatient.
- Diplomatic: cautious, tame, or courteous.
- Passionate: zealous, romantic, or obsessive.
- Rational: practical, standoffsh, or cold.
- Honest: guileless, sincere, or straightforward.
- Deceptive: dishonest, manipulative, or shrewd.

Does anyone know exactly how they work? They look like they could be 5 spectrums (eg: Benevolent/Cruel, Honest/Deceptive). If not, can I have a reputation for both benevolance and cruelty?

Do we know what numbers you need to cross over into each reputation category?

What are the "titles" of these categories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's research time!

I can't give you the information on what effect certain personality combinations will have on NPC interactions - I might test that later when I get to an NPC that reacts somehow. However the underlying mechanics are as follows:

- As you guessed, each choice attached to personality trait increments an internal counter related to it. According to [wiki](http://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Disposition#Disposition_gain) amount of points gained through single response may be 1, 3 or 7, during my (non-extensive) research however I have not encountered 3 and 7 kind.
- All of 10 personality traits have their separate counters, not connected to one another. Cruel choice does not decrease benevolence etc. If any grouping happens - it is at the level of NPC reactions.
- As a consequence, **you can be both `Benevolent 4` and `Cruel 4` at the same time**. In principle at least, I do not know if there are enough responses to actually achieve that.

As for the amount required for each level:

- Level 1 requires **4** points
- Level 2 requires **12** points, except for `Deceptive` which requires **8**
- Level 3 requires **25** points, except for `Deceptive` which requires **14**
- Level 4 requires **45** points, except for `Deceptive` which requires **24**

**4 is the highest level achievable.**

Comment: Just wanted to add that you should be cautious when leveling negative reputations as these can lead to severe consequences. For example, in the quest "The Parable of Wael", if you choose to follow Wael's instruction AND you have a `Deceptive` reputation of 2 or more, you forfeit the quest rewards. This is problematic because you loose the non-violent option of gaining access to a locked room, unless of course your character is evil and you intend to slaughter your way through.