# Do dispositions really affect the game? What are the reactions to dispositions?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

Does anybody know how dispositions affect the game beside playing paladin or priest? Are there some specific results of your current dispositions that alternate dialogues or anything?

In the Disposition article in `pillarsofeternity.gamepedia`, there are only five listed reaction changes in the whole game. Is that it? So are dispositions (meaning besides playing paladin/priest) in fact only some kind of evaluation of how you played the game or do they really affect the gameplay?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/212104/how-does-personality-reputation-work/212174#comment289866_212174 mentions sixth game-changing reaction. Also, NPCs mention dispositions quite often, though it would be hard to test every time whether something important changes or is it just flavour text.

Comment: I have run into a number of NPCs reacting to my reputations, more than 6 certainly. Though I have not kept a record of who and when.

Answer (score 3):

Some quests might failed if you are of a certain disposition. For instance, when attempting the **Parable of Wael** quest:

> If you hide the scroll and instead of returning it, the quest-giver
>  will believe that it is indeed what the goddess want if you have
>  Honest 2. However, if you are known to be deceptive, she would not
>  believe you

In the quest **Sacrificial Bloodline**, you'll get alternate dialogue from the Simoc if you have at least Benevolent 2. He'll comment on you finding their ways too squeamish and wonder if you're able to handle what he wants you to do.